# Using a for loop to iterate from an array to a list

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, export-to-csv

I have a text file that is divided up into many sections, each about 10 or so lines long. I'm reading in the file using File.ReadAllLines into an array, one line per element of the array, and I'm then I'm trying to parse each section of the file to bring back just some of the data. I'm storing the results in a list, and hoping to export the list to csv ultimately.

My for loop is giving me trouble, as it loops through the right amount of times, but only pulls the data from the first section of the text file each time rather than pulling the data from the first section and then moving on and pulling the data from the next section. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong either in my for loop or for each loop. Any clues to help me solve this would be much appreciated! Thanks
David

My code so far:

```
namespace ParseAndExport
{
    class Program
    {

        static readonly string sourcefile = @"Path";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] readInLines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcefile);
            int counter = 0;
            int holderCPStart = counter + 3;//Changed Paths will be an different number of lines each time, but will always start 3 lines after the startDiv

            /*Need to find the start of the section and the end of the section and parse the bit in between.
             * Also need to identify the blank line that occurs in each section as it is essentially a divider too.*/
            int startDiv = Array.FindIndex(readInLines, counter, hyphens72);
            int blankLine = Array.FindIndex(readInLines, startDiv, emptyElement);
            int endDiv = Array.FindIndex(readInLines, counter + 1, hyphens72);

            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            //Test to see if FindIndexes work. Results should be 0, 7, 9 for 1st section of sourcefile
            /*Console.WriteLine(startDiv);
            Console.WriteLine(blankLine);
            Console.WriteLine(endDiv);*/

            //Check how long the file is so that for testing we know how long the while loop should run for
            //Console.WriteLine(readInLines.Length); 
            //sourcefile has 5255 lines (elements) in the array


           for (int i = 0; i <= readInLines.Length; i++)
            {

                if (i == startDiv)
                {

                    results = (readInLines[i + 1].Split('|').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList());
                    string holderCP = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, readInLines, holderCPStart, (blankLine - holderCPStart - 1)).Trim();
                    results.Add(holderCP);
                    string comment = string.Join(" ", readInLines, blankLine + 1, (endDiv - (blankLine + 1)));//in case the comment is more than one line long
                    results.Add(comment);

                    i = i + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = i + 1;
                }


                foreach (string result in results)
                {


                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }



                //csvcontent.AppendLine("Revision Number, Author, Date, Time, Count of Lines, Changed Paths, Comments");

                /* foreach (string result in results)
                 {

                     for (int x = 0; x <= results.Count(); x++)
                     {

                         StringBuilder csvcontent = new StringBuilder();
                         csvcontent.AppendLine(results[x] + "," + results[x + 1] + "," + results[x + 2] + "," + results[x + 3] + "," + results[x + 4] + "," + results[x + 5]);
                         x = x + 6;
                         string csvpath = @"addressforcsvfile";
                         File.AppendAllText(csvpath, csvcontent.ToString());


                     }

                 }*/

            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }







        private static bool hyphens72(String h)
        {
            if (h == "------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }



        }

        private static bool emptyElement(String ee)
        {
            if (ee == "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Does each section begin and/or end with all of those hyphens? IMO the first step to simplify this is to separate *reading* and *processing* this into two distinct tasks. Perhaps create a list of list of strings. Every time you encounter the hyphens, start a new list and fill it with all of the lines of text until you get to the next "------------------". Then repeat. When you're done, you'll have a list of lists, where each lnner list is a chunk of lines between the hyphens. Now splitting it is done and you can process them. But don't try to split them and process them in one method.

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems wrong. There are issues with the code in itself also. I am unsure what precisely you're trying to do. Anyway, a few hints that I hope will help:

1. The  if (i == startDiv) checks to see if I equals startDiv. I assume the logic that happens when this condition is met, is what you refer to as "pulls the data from the first section". That's correct, given you only run this code when I equals startDiv.
2. You increase the counter I inside the for loop, which in itself also increases the counter i.
3. If the issue in 2. wouldn't exists then I'd suggest to not do the same operation "i = i + 1" in both the true and false conditions of the if (i == startDiv).

Given I assume this file might actually be massive, it's probably a good idea to not store it in memory, but just read the file line by line and process line by line. There's currently no obvious reason why you'd want to consume this amount of memory, unless it's because of the convenience of this API "File.ReadAllLines(sourcefile)". I wouldn't be too scared to read the file like this:

```
Try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      // process the line.
    }
}
```

You can skip the lines until you've passed where the line equals hyphens72.

Then for each line, you process the line with the code you provided in the true case of  (i == startDiv), or at least, from what you described, this is what I assume you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Jo, that has given me some things to focus in on and fix. Many thanks

Comment: Thanks Jo, I haven't heard of BufferedReader previously, but will look it up. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to grab all of the lines in a file that are not "------" and put them into a list of strings.

You can try this:

```
var lineswithoutdashes = readInLines.Where(x => x != hyphens72).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Now you can take this list and do the split with a '|' to extract the fields you wanted

Comment: Thanks Kevin, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are a several things which could be improved.

- I would use `ReadLines` over `File.ReadAllLines(` because ReadAllLines reads all the lines at ones. ReadLines will stream it.
- With the line `results = (readInLines[i + 1].Split('|').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList());` you're overwriting the previous results list. You'd better use `results.AddRange()` to add new results.
- `for (int i = 0; i <= readInLines.Length; i++)` means when the length = 10 it will do 11 iterations. (1 too many)  *(remove the `=`)*
- `Array.FindIndex(readInLines, counter, hyphens72);` will do a scan. On large files it will take ages to completely read them and search in it. **Try to touch a single line only ones.**

I cannot test what you are doing, but here's a hint:

```
IEnumerable<string> readInLines = File.ReadLines(sourcefile);

bool started = false;

List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach(var line in readInLines)
{
    // skip empty lines
    if(emptyElement(line))
        continue;

    // when dashes are found, flip a boolean to activate the reading mode.
    if(hyphens72(line))
    {
        // flip state.. (start/end)
        started != started;
    }

    if(started)
    {
        // I don't know what you are doing here precisely, do what you gotta do. ;-)
        results.AddRange((line.Split('|').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList()));
        string holderCP = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, readInLines, holderCPStart, (blankLine - holderCPStart - 1)).Trim();
        results.Add(holderCP);
        string comment = string.Join(" ", readInLines, blankLine + 1, (endDiv - (blankLine + 1)));//in case the comment is more than one line long
        results.Add(comment);
    }

}

foreach (string result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, looks like I need to rethink my logic, but great to have the input to get me pointed in a better direction. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`int startDiv` will return the **line number** that contains `hyphens72`.

So your current `for` loop will only copy to results for the single line that matches the calculated line number.

I guess you want to search the postion of `startDiv` in the current line?

```
  const string hyphens72;
  // loop over lines
  for (var lineNumber = 0; lineNumber  <= readInLines.Length; lineNumber++) {
      string currentLine = readInLines[lineNumber];
      int startDiv = currentLine.IndexOf(hyphens72);
      // loop over characters in line
      for (var charIndex = 0; charIndex < currentLine.Length; charIndex++) {
          if (charIndex  == startDiv) {
              var currentCharacter = currentLine[charIndex];
              // write to result ...
          }
          else {
              continue; // skip this character
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with a class like this. I don't know whether each section begins with a row of hyphens, or if it's just in between. This should handle either scenario.

What this is going to do is take your giant list of strings (the lines in the file) and break it into chunks - each chunk is a set of lines (10 or so lines, according to your OP.)

The reason is that it's unnecessarily complicated to try to read the file, looking for the hyphens, and process the contents of the file at the same time. Instead, one class takes the input and breaks it into chunks. That's all it does.

Another class might read the file and pass its contents to this class to break them up. Then the output is the individual chunks of text.

Another class can then process those individual sections of 10 or so lines without having to worry about hyphens or what separates on chunk from another.

Now that each of these classes is doing its own thing, it's easier to write unit tests for each of them separately. You can test that your "processing" class receives an array of 10 or so lines and does whatever it's supposed to do with them.

```
public class TextSectionsParser
{
    private readonly string _delimiter;

    public TextSectionsParser(string delimiter)
    {
        _delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ParseSections(IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        var result = new List<List<string>>();
        var currentList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (line == _delimiter)
            {
                if(currentList.Any())
                    result.Add(currentList);
                currentList = new List<string>();
            }
            else
            {
                currentList.Add(line);
            }
        }
        if (currentList.Any() && !result.Contains(currentList))
        {
            result.Add(currentList);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```